# Realm & LiveData - Transformations.map not posting List to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, realm, android-livedata

I need to load sorted data from Realm database. I have tried to load data directly and post value to MutableLiveData:

```
mTracks.postValue(mRepository.getAllSorted(sortingDirection, sortedBy));
```

This is RealmRepository:

```
public List<Track> getAllSorted(int sortingDirection, int sortedBy) {
    return mRealm.where(Track.class).sort("date", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
}
```

But this is giving error:

> IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm
>   objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Then I tried different ways to overcome this issue and found good post from Realm team:

https://academy.realm.io/posts/android-architecture-components-and-realm/

According to the post I created LiveRealmData:

```
public class LiveRealmData<T extends RealmModel> extends MutableLiveData<RealmResults<T>> {
private RealmResults<T> results;
    private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener =
        new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) {
                setValue(results);
            }
    };
    public LiveRealmData(RealmResults<T> realmResults) {
        results = realmResults;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        results.addChangeListener(listener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        results.removeChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And changed RealmRepository part to this code:

```
public LiveRealmData<Track> getAllSorted(int sortingDirection, int sortedBy) {
    return asRealmLiveData(mRealm.where(Track.class).sort("date", Sort.ASCENDING).findAllAsync());
}

private LiveRealmData asRealmLiveData(RealmResults<Track> realmResults) {
    return new LiveRealmData<>(realmResults);
}
```

In ResultsViewModel, I am getting LiveRealmData and trying to convert it to MutableLiveData:

```
public void loadTracksSorted(int sortingDirection, int sortedBy) {
    LiveRealmData<Track> tracks = mRepository.getAllSorted(sortingDirection, sortedBy);
    mTracks = (MutableLiveData<List<Track>>) Transformations.map(tracks, new Function<RealmResults<Track>, List<Track>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Track> apply(RealmResults<Track> tracks) {
            List<Track> trackList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Track track: tracks){
                trackList.add(track);
            }
            return trackList;
        }
    });
}
```

But result is empty.

My question: how to post data to MutableLiveData using Transformations.map method?

Comment: Did you attach an observer to "mTracks" variable? AFAIK, Transformations.map uses a MediatorLiveData inside, and that routes its observed state to the livedata it observes ("tracks" LiveData, in that case). So, if you don't observe mTracks, maybe tracks is not observed also, and onActive() method is never triggered, hence the list is empty.

Comment: Yes, I attached an observer to mTracks variable. When load data from Realm database without sorting, it is showing successfully. But I am not sure it was successful because it is without sorting or it is loaded before UI created (it is called Fragment's onActivityCreated method)

Comment: `Then I tried different ways to overcome this issue` -- Have you tried not assuming that `mRealm` is always accessed on the same thread? After all, you seem to be using it from multiple threads. So maybe you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I found the reason why realm was used in different threads, it was because of DiffUtil in ListAdapter. I found out that DiffUtil uses realm objects in another thread and caused error. I replaced ListAdapter<Track, ResultHolder> to RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultHolder>, removed DiffUtil, implemented required methods and it solved my problem :)

Comment: Ah yeah. RealmResults can also give you the changes if used with OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener, then DiffUtil won't be needed.

Comment: @JoeRakhimov It means there is no way that we can use the ListAdapter with DiffUtil functionality with ream live data observer?